# Drivers issues on Lenovo yoga 7i with I7-13700H with Linux

Tags: drivers, lenovo

In my new pc i have tried to install different Linux distros such as Ubuntu 22 Ubuntu 23 and Manjaro. Both of their installers are not able to be run to my machine due to driver issues I think. The mouse moves very slowly and it is impossible to install them. But I have apparently all drivers working including wifi ones. With Ubuntu 20 I managed to install and make it work but WiFi drivers are not working. Moreover I can't change the screen resolution and refresh rate.
I simply need to know if I have to wait more for drivers or if it is better than I give back and change my PC. Thank you in advance for your time.